# My SQL Server query does not return the expected result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filtering, multiple-conditions

My SQL Server query does not return the expected result when I add conditions.
My part with this condition is ignored :

```
chartTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2013-06-01 00:00:00' )
```

It doesn't show all the record after '2013-06-01 00:00:00' but works when it's the only condition on the query

Complete query:

```
SELECT TOP(100) 
    CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST([chartTime] AS float) * 24.0, 0) / 24.0)[chartTime], 
    [interventionId], [terseForm], [verboseForm], 
    [attributeId], [encounterId]
FROM
    [CISReportingDB].[dbo].[PtAssessment]
WHERE
    chartTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2013-06-01 00:00:00') 
    AND interventionId IN (SELECT [interventionId] 
                           FROM [CISReportingDB].[dbo].[PtAssessment]
                           WHERE interventionId IN (6659, 9899, 11870)) 
    OR verboseForm LIKE 'sibil. exp%' 
    OR attributeId LIKE '67194%'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need some parentheses in your where clause...

```
WHERE
    chartTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2013-06-01 00:00:00') 
    AND 
    (interventionId IN (SELECT [interventionId] 
                           FROM [CISReportingDB].[dbo].[PtAssessment]
                           WHERE interventionId IN (6659, 9899, 11870)) 
    OR verboseForm LIKE 'sibil. exp%' 
    OR attributeId LIKE '67194%')
```

This will return rows where the `chartTime >= '2013-06-01 00:00:00'`your date... and **one of** the other conditions exits.  Without the parentheses, your have conflicting AND/OR logic meaning it would return rows where `verboseForm LIKE 'sibil. exp%' OR attributeId LIKE '67194%'`

Otherwise, you'd need to make sure there are rows which actually fit your filtering... meaning the `interventionId` is either 6659,9899, or 11870 or the `verboseForm LIKE 'sibil. exp%' OR attributeId LIKE '67194%'`.

Lastly, the IN clause is redundant... you can just list the values once:

```
WHERE
    chartTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2013-06-01 00:00:00') 
    AND 
    (interventionId IN (6659, 9899, 11870) 
    OR verboseForm LIKE 'sibil. exp%' 
    OR attributeId LIKE '67194%')
```

Comment: No problem @Zenix